# How can I restrict characters of a md-chip value?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using md-chips. Now I want to limit the character as 10.

I tried md-maxlength, one custome directive to limit characters but its all working in textarea and input not in chips

Comment: Can you post examples of what you've tried

Comment: Do you mean a character limit of the text inside the chip, or a chip limit, meaning you can only add 10 chips for example

Comment: I asked character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Chip Limit**

---

Limits the count of chips you can add to the 'chips' model:

```
<md-chips ng-model="myItems" placeholder="Add an item" md-max-chips="5">
</md-chips>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/290/

You cannot add more than 5 chips to that input.

Unfortunately there's very little validation control for the md-chips directive:

From ([AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips))

> Validation
>
> - allow a validation callback
> - hilighting style for invalid chips

---

**Character Chip Limit**

---

If you're after a character limit, you can do something like this:

```
<md-chips ng-model="myItems" placeholder="Add an item" md-max-chips="5"  md-on-add="validateChip($chip)">
</md-chips>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']).controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myItems = [];
    $scope.validateChip = validateChip;

    var characterLimit = 10;
    function validateChip($chip) {
        if (!$chip) return;
        // check if the current string length is greater than or equal to a character limit.
        if ($chip.length >= characterLimit) {
            alert('whooaaa, you breached the limit yo!');
            // remove the last added item.
            $scope.myItems.pop();
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/291/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Its working perfectly. How can I restrict typing after exceeding the limit?

Comment: Doesn't look like the md-chips allows this functionality. I looked into re-setting the value back to what is was before the character limit was breached, but doesn't look like there's a way.

Comment: Instead of pop() is there any way to truncate the length of recently added chip?

Comment: I added this  to your code ` $chip  = $chip.trunc(characterLimit-1);`  For the time being  this will solve my problem. Thank you once again :)  ` if ($chip.length >= characterLimit) {
            alert('whooaaa, you breached the limit yo!');
            // remove the last added item.
            $scope.myItems.pop();$chip  = $chip.trunc(characterLimit-1);
        }'

Comment: $chip.trunc is not a public method? @Hanna